Prove that a logarithmic function has maximum $0$
How do I prove that $$\log_{1/3} (|x-3|+1)$$ has maximum value $0$?
Do I have to equate this log function and $0$ to find out if it equals $0$, or I need to solve this some other way?
(Feel free to edit my question if it doesn't align with the guidelines, I'm not good at forming questions.)

is $log_{1/3}(x)$ a decreasing function?

What is the multiple math concepts? The title and body of the question seem completely unrelated.

I $x=28/9,$ then $x-3=1/9$ and $\log_{1/3}|x-3|=2.$ So this is not true. Is there a reason you think it is true?

the $1$ is part of the log

Think about the meaning of $\log_{1/3}$ and try to visualize the graph of the given function.

If it is $\log_{1/3}(|\dots|+1),$ OP should put parentheses around the argument to $\log$.

@ThomasAndrews what is OP?

original poster

OP=Original poster. User @fGDu94 was posting the correction, as if they were sure, but the person asking the question is the only one sure what they meant to ask.

@MH.Lee I'm sorry for the misguiding title, I wrote that as the title because while solving I felt I needed to use logarithm, inequality (somehow, couldn't figure out but just felt I needed to) , so I was confused as to what to title the question as.

So can my question be answered now, if there aren't any other faults?

We can see that $\log_{\frac{1}{3}}(x)$ is a decreasing function. So its maximum value is attained when $x$ is minimum or in your case we want $|x-3|+1$ to be minimum.
Recall that $|x|\ge0$ so the minimum value of $|x-3|+1$ is $1$ which is attained when $x=3$
Now it is well known that $$\boxed{\log_{\frac{1}{3}}(1)=0}$$

As $1/3<1$, $f(x)=\log_{1/3}(x)$
is a decreasing function. So its maximum value is attained when $x
$ is minimum in the domain.
As $$|x-3|+1\geq 1$$ with equality at $x=3$, the maximum of $f$ is attained at $x=3$, with value $0$.

$\lvert x-3\rvert\ge0$, so $\lvert x-3\rvert+1\ge1$.
That means $(1/3)^{\log_{1/3}(|x-3|+1)}=|x-3|+1\ge1,$
so $\log_{1/3}(|x-3|+1)\le0$, and equality holds when $|x-3|=0$.
